# How to add a new line without breaking the current line?

Tags: emacs

In vim, I can do this in command mode by typing 'o', which will add a new line below the cursor, and enter the insert mode.

Is there an equivalent in emacs?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The command <kbd>C-o</kbd> `open-line` that others have suggested is not quite the same as <kbd>o</kbd> in vi, because it splits the current line and lets the cursor remain in the current line.

You get the exact same effect as vi's <kbd>o</kbd> with two strokes: <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>, which moves the cursor to the end of the current line and then inserts a new line, which leaves the cursor at the beginning of that line.

You could bind that sequence to a key of its own (perhaps overriding the existing definition of <kbd>C-o</kbd>), but I doubt if it's worth the trouble.

(Incidentally, the symmetric sequence <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> gives you the effect of vi's capital <kbd>O</kbd>, inserting a line *before* the current line.)

Comment: I just occasionally found this great key in vi, and I am sure that it  is worth to bind to *C-o*. It is needed very often, I am wonder, why I haven't guessed to do this before.

Comment: A better command is `C-e C-o`, as this will avoid wrapping the current line if auto-fill-mode is enabled.

Comment: Even better: `M-m C-o` which keeps your indentation.

Answer (score 21):

have you solved your problem?

I just solved this problem. Feel free to use this code :)
You can **bind to every key** you like in the `global-set-key`,also to replace `newline-and-indent` with `newline` **in case** you don't like the new line to be indented.

```
;; newline-without-break-of-line
(defun newline-without-break-of-line ()
  "1. move to end of the line.
  2. insert newline with index"

  (interactive)
  (let ((oldpos (point)))
    (end-of-line)
    (newline-and-indent)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'newline-without-break-of-line)
```

Comment: and that's the best of emacs: you can achieve everything you want by elisp-ing it. There are not limits nor constraints. You can make emacs to suit you because it's highly customizable!

Answer (score 10):

I am using prelude, and <kbd>S-RET</kbd> is equivalent to vi's <kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-RET</kbd> is equivalent to vi's <kbd>O</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `emacs 25` and I have something like this:

```
;; Insert new line below current line
;; and move cursor to new line
;; it will also indent newline
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") (lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (end-of-line)
                   (newline-and-indent)))
;; Insert new line above current line
;; and move cursor to previous line (newly inserted line)
;; it will also indent newline
;; TODO: right now I am unable to goto previous line, FIXIT
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-return>") (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                       (beginning-of-line)
                       (newline-and-indent)
                       (previous-line)))
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 2):

I use following key bindings make it work similar to vim's o and O:

```
<pre>
;; vi-like line insertion
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") (lambda () (interactive)(beginning-of-line)(open-line 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") (lambda () (interactive)(end-of-line)(newline)))
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Emacs 24.Insert the line to ".**emacs**" file.

```
;; Move cursor to end of current line
;; Insert new line below current line
;; it will also indent newline
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") (lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (end-of-line)
                   (newline-and-indent)))

;; Move cursor to previous line 
;; Go to end of the line
;; Insert new line below current line (So it actually insert new line above with indentation)
;; it will also indent newline
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-return>") (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                       (previous-line)
                       (end-of-line)
                       (newline-and-indent)
                       ))
```

- **`<C + Return>`** that means **`<Ctrl + Enter>`** for *new line below*

and

- **`<C + S + Return>`** that means **`<Ctrl + Shift + Enter>`** for *new line above*.

  Both will indent also. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-o</kbd> will run [`open-line`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Blank-Lines.html) which will insert a blank line after the cursor. By default emacs is already in "insert mode" unless you are in a read-only buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration could help:

```
(defun newline-without-break-of-line ()
  "1. move to end of the line.
2. open new line and move to new line"
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line)
  (open-line 1)
  (right-char))
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-return>") 'newline-without-break-of-line)
```